# How can I run UI Tests on android library modules that use databinding?

Tags: android, android-library, android-databinding

I have a library module, in which I use Databinding, and I need to test it with Espresso, but my tests fail with `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/my/package/BR;`.

Changing the module type to `application` resolves the issue and my tests run fine, so I am assuming that the `BR` class is excluded when running a `library` module.

Does anyone know how to keep the BR class for libraries, or some other way to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If someone faces this in the future, I had to use an auxiliary application module just to develop my tests, adding the library module as a dependency.